# can we containerize the asp.net website?But there is no option in vs 2017 for that

Tags: asp.net, docker, web, visual-studio-2017, containers

Customer wants to containerize the website.But I didnot find any options available to add docker support over there in vs2017.Is there any way available?

Comment: quick google gave me [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-2.1) and [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/containerized-lifecycle-architecture/design-develop-containerized-apps/visual-studio-tools-for-docker).. havent tried myself.. but your question is pretty broad and someone might did not sit well with it :(

Comment: You can do ASP.NET containers with Docker with Windows Container support, or .Net Core containers with Linux support. Just depends on which stack you're looking at using. VS 2017 already has Docker support options baked in, including orchestration default. Sounds like you need to update visual studio.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend going through the very brief and thorough [Getting Started](https://docs.docker.com/get-started/) tutorial for Docker: it has you build a website from scratch and shouldn't take you longer than two hours from start to finish. By going through this tutorial, I think you will find many of your and your client's (and other's) concerns addressed.

In summary, you will:

1. Add a Dockerfile to the top level of your project directory
2. Define the image with all of it's dependencies
3. Build the image using your source files and produce a container
4. Iterate over steps 2 and 3 (here) until you have a correctly build the image
5. Run the container and check out your website running on your localhost
6. Done!

Be sure to follow [Docker's best practices](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/).

There is already an [official .Net image](https://store.docker.com/images/dotnet), use it (not some uncertified image)!